# javascript created iframe auto-height

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm using Javascript to have dropdown box that open iframe below with the selected page.
The page below is a dynamic graph page and therefore the height of it.
To see the page without scrolling in the iframe i've added 1320% to it.
How can I do this dynamically based on the page ?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadFrame()
        {
        var s=document.getElementById("report_type").value;
        document.getElementById("loadContainer").innerHTML=""
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = s;
        iframe.style.width = 100+"%";
        iframe.style.height = 1320+"%";
        iframe.frameBorder = 0;
        document.getElementById("loadContainer").appendChild(iframe);
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: Currently 1320+"%";, with PX it didnt' work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the body of the html element and set the height to the iframe:-

```
   var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = 'test.html';
    iframe.style.width = "100%";
    iframe.onload = function(){
        iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.margin = 5+'px';
        iframe.style.height = (iframe.contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight+10)+"px";
    }
    iframe.frameBorder = 0;
    document.getElementById("loadContainer").appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Not working :(  the window open at full width but 20% of the height.

Comment: Have you written my code within the loadFrame function which will be called onload of body? I've test my code locally and it worked, with no issue. The height of the iframe will be equal to the height of the content within the iframe.

Comment: Can I get the src of the iframe you are assigning, so that I can test it?

Comment: How can I post my code ? this comment wont allow it.

Comment: I don't want the code, can I get url of the page, you're assigning to the iframe.

Comment: You can try:-
 iframe.style.height = (iframe.contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight+10); alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight);

Comment: If you get the exact height of the content within the iframe that the code is working fine, otherwise, there is some float property in the html so that js is not getting the exact height, then I need to look into your html.

Comment: Sorry but its internal server. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I can't do anything with internal server error. That means the website you're opening in the iframe, has internal server error. It's your local webpage then you've fix it. My code can only fix the iframe height issue.